# How to run a Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer via CLI commands for 24 hours

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a requirement, where we would need to showcase the resiliency of a kafka cluster. To prove this, we have a use case where we need to run a producer and consumer ( I am thinking kafka-console-producer and kafla-console-consumer) preferably via cli commands and/or scripts to run continuously for 24hrs. We are not concerned with the message size and contents; preferably the size can be as small as possible and messages be any random value, say the present timestamp.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing preventing you from doing this, and the problem isn't unique to Kafka.

You can use `nohup` to run a script as a daemon, otherwise, the commands will terminate when that console session ends. You could also use `cron` to schedule any script, a minimum of every minute...

Or you can write your own app with a simple `while(true)` loop.

Regardless, you will want a proess supervisor to truly ensure the command remains running at all times.

Comment: ok, so say I run the script using nohup, e.g. kafka console producer, how do I automatically push data on the console?

Comment: Use `while true` bash loop?

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand, would you be able to share a code snippet or a pseudo script

Comment: `example.sh` - `while true; echo "test" | kafka-console-producer  ... ; done`... `nohup example.sh &`

Comment: Or use python - https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

Comment: Keep in mind. This will certainly fill up your Kafka disks, rather quickly, depending on what you're sending and how quickly, which may cause it to crash.

Comment: Also, if you use Kubernetes, then Strimzi Operator has a canary process that already does this for you.